# Double pulse test time interval

Tags: mosfet, simulation, pspice, waveform, testing

Keeping all other parameters (like DC bus voltage, Bus capacitance, Inductor value, etc.) fixed, and only changing the time interval between the two pulses, why would there be a difference in the peak drain current of the MOSFET (I am referring to the value attained by drain current during turn OFF of the second pulse)?

When I keep a 100 us gap between the two pulses, the peak current is ~7 A, whereas, with same conditions other than the gap being 25 microseconds, I get a peak current of nearly 10 A. Why is this so?

This is the example image of drain current. Experimental waveform shows VDS(yellow), VGS(purple, scale of Ch3 is 20V not 2 V), ID(blue)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this measured data or simulation results? What is the signal that is causing these current pulses? If it is measured, how are you making the measurements? What is the time scale for your graph?

Comment: Can you add a schematic, to avoid guessing of what you have there and how it's driven?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without a schematic of the circuit that's demonstrating this behaviour. All else is guesswork and crystal ball gazing. Unless of course it is intended for the Puzzling stack,  'what circuit configuration would be consistent with this behaviour?'

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the posted waveform is simulated, but it's not matching with experimental results (peak=~7A) with a 2.5 microseconds gap between 2 pulses

Comment: @Neil_UK sorry, I assumed DPT was a universal circuit configuration. Please see the edits

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen sorry about that, please see the circuit I added.

Comment: The point of a double-pulse test is to have the simplest test needed to show a clamped inductive load turn-on (rising edge of second pulse). Normally, what I have done to adjust that current is change the width of pulse 1, and have pulse 2 start as soon as practical.

Comment: @W5VO oh so there is no fixed time after which to start 2nd pulse...i see. Here I am trying to understand why my simulation does not give the same result as the experimental one, it matches only when interval is 100 us long and not 2.5us....

Comment: Andy's answer is correct in identifying *why* changing the pulse separation gives you different current values. If you're getting different peak currents for identical inputs  (pulse width, spacing; VBUS) between simulation and bench testing, then look at your inductor value. You live by \$\dfrac{V}{L}=\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ in this test. At least on your simulation, monitor inductor current as well. In my tests, I only varied the width of pulse 1. The spacing between pulses as well as the width of pulse 2 were constant.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the waveforms, I would say that your circuit is some kind of switching converter and, the MOSFET in question is in series with an inductor. That inductor charges up linearly with current when the MOSFET is activated. And, indeed that is the initial waveform shape I see.

So, for the first pulse shown in your picture, the inductor current begins at 0 amps and rapidly attains slightly over 5 amps during the MOSFET activation period. Then, taking a guess, I would say that the inductor current (or current in a coupled inductor) ramps down much more slowly but, after on "off" duration of 100 μs, that inductor current is probably close to around 2 amps: -

[image]

If the MOSFET is reactivated, the inductor current starts ramping up from just over 2 amps. I note that the actual ramping part of the current in the 2nd pulse remains just over 5 amps so this makes sense to me. The final current will be about 2.3 amps plus 5.2 amps = 7.5 amps.

It all sounds like a switching converter operating in CCM. So, if you tried shortening the time delay between pulses to 25 μs you might see this sort of peak current: -

[image]

So, after 25 μs the current in the inductor may have fallen to 4.6 amps (found graphically) then, when the MOSFET activates, the raamp up in current begins from 4.6 amps and rises 5.2 more amps to finish at 9.8 amps.

**Circuit diagram revealed**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! But I am still confused why the experimental results differ by such a big margin.....any thoughts on that would be very helpful.

Comment: I got nearly 10 A in simulating with exact same parameters as hardware (~7A), so I think stray inductances might make experimental current lower than simulated? Am I right in thinking so?

Comment: @SM32 - this appears to be the question you asked: *When I keep a 100 us gap between the two pulses, the peak current is ~7 A, whereas, with same conditions other than the gap being 25 microseconds, I get a peak current of nearly 10 A. Why is this so?* - as far as I'm aware that has been answered. What is it about my answer that confuses you? Stray inductances might make a bit of a difference when you come to build it but, not too much. Stray capacitances might make a bigger difference.